# Eclipse not showing search results in c++ perspective

Tags: eclipse

Using Eclipse Oxygen.3 Release (4.7.3) and in c++ perspective search results window will not show. Even if I do Window->Show View->Search/classic Search. It is very annoying. Search works in different perspective. Google search reveals nothing. 
I tried restart, tried running eclipse.exe -clean from cmd. I cannot do a re install (have everything set up nice, except search results not showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do 
`Window->Perspective->Rest Perspective.` 
It solves the problem. 
//Note: it will destroy your perspective settings (set them to default), so use this only if you don't need to keep your settings.